# Magento 1.9.2 - Prices are updated in the back end but not in the front end after import

Tags: magento-1.9, php, price, frontend, backend

I made an import with the eMagicOne program using the Bridge connection to update all site prices. In the backend the prices are all up to date, but in the front end I keep seeing the old prices. This type of problem occurs only for two stores of the site. Only in one store I see in the front end the new prices.

I've really tried everything. I did the reindex, cleaning the cache etc ... but it did not work. What could be the problem?

Thanks for every help

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the prices perstore by default you will be using Default store.

So if you are working in multistore website you need to import the prices for all the stores.

Try doing that and then reindex the website again and it will work

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the solution. My wrong, sorry. When i imported all new prices i chose only default store and and I did not repeat the import process for each website.

Comment: Glad, to get you working :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like indexing issue, try re-indexing Product Indexesunder system ->Index Management. If unsuccessful, also try other indexes and clear cache.

Comment: Hi man, thanks for the reply. I have tried multiple times to update all the indexes and clean the cache but it did not work. The shop continues to show the old prices. How could I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you're saying it happens only for some stores in your setup, maybe you didn't setup this store to use different prices? You can always check if the "Use default value" is checked for the price (on store level).

[image: storeprice]

Comment: Thanks for the reply man. This could be a just solution. :)